# React Router v4 lifecycle events

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Upgrading my application to React Router v4 I'm struggling to find a clean way to implement the old onUpdate logic which I previously used the hide a popup menu on navigation.

The only way I can see in the documentation is to take advantage of the [route render](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/#route.render) method but it seems much more complicated than before - any easier solutions?

```
const HidePopupThenRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={matchProps => {
    hidePopup();
    return <Component {...matchProps}/>
  }}/>
)

<HidePopupThenRoute path="/" component={MyComponent}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relatively clean solution [was suggested on GitHub](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/122#issuecomment-309246808). What it comes down to is that you read the Router's history from [React's Context API](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html), where it gets populated by React Router. You can do so by defining the `contextTypes` property in your component:

```js
static contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object
};
```

That will make sure that the Router is attached to that component. You can then use that the access the router and its history from the context, and add a callback that gets executed on history changes:

```js
this.context.router.history.listen(hidePopup)
```

You'll probably want to do that in `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't consider that too complicated, but I can understand it not looking right to make imperative calls inside of a render function.

One alternative would be to create an `OnUpdate` component that listens for location changes and calls some function when the happen.

You can see the [source code](https://github.com/pshrmn/rrc/blob/master/src/OnUpdate.js) for an implementation of this that I wrote. You can either use that or replicate your own component with similar functionality. Basically, all that it does is subscribe to the `history` object and calls whatever function you pass to it when the location changes.

```js
const MyComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <OnUpdate call={hideProps} />
    <h1>My Component</h1>
    <p>...</p> 
  </div>
)
```